# Boot error due to missing files and interface not showing well on "try ubuntu"

Tags: boot-repair, busybox

How do I solve this error when trying to turn on Ubuntu 22.04?

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device.Common problems:
-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
-check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
UUID does not exist
```

I also tried using *Try Ubuntu* and the system was blank.

Comment: What is the actual question this appears to be a collection of error messages. What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Is error from installed system or from live installer on USB drive? If you have Boot-Repair working on live installer, post link to summary report.